# variable has not changed? calling through function of a vector

Tags: c++

Here is my code, i have done multiple tests to make sure the adding of objects into vector is correct. So i try to advance from there a little more.
My program is that a Voter class will a vector of BallotPaper, whereas a BallotPaper will have a vector of Candidate. The Candidate class will have a private variable called _votecount.

What I want to perform is that, I want to increase _votecount through Voter, using function `Vote(int,int)`.

However in my case the _votecount does not increment as I have expected and I cant figured out, probably something obvious, thus I appreciate any inputs.

Here is my main:

```
int main()
{
    Date d1(2018, 10, 1);// new Date object
    Member m1("Alice", 100, "Engineering", 012, d1, PositionType::Normal);
    bool check = m1.CheckEligibility();
    cout << check<<"\n";

    Voter v1("Ailee", 100, "Engineering", 012, d1, PositionType::Normal);
    if (v1.getName() == "Ailee")
    {
         cout << "\nTrue1\n";   // Yes
    }

    BallotPaper bp1(PositionType::President);
    v1.AddBallotPaper(bp1);
    if (v1.getBallotPapers()[0].getPositionBP() == PositionType::President)
    {
        cout << "\nTrue2\n"; //Yes
    }

     Candidate c1("Ailee", 100, "Engineering", 012, d1, PositionType::Normal);
     v1.getBallotPapers()[0].AddCandidate(c1);
     if (v1.getBallotPapers()[0].getCandidates()[0].getName() == "Ailee")
     {
         cout << "\nTrue3\n";   //Yes
     }

// Voter cast vote to increase candidate count
    v1.Vote(0, 0);

    if (c1.getVoteCount() == 1)
    {
         cout << "\nDONE\n";     //ERROR HERE!
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Voter class

```
class Voter :public Member
{
    private:
        std::vector<BallotPaper> _bp;  
    public:
        Voter::Voter(std::string a, int b, std::string c, int d, Date e, PositionType f) : Member(a, b, c, d, e, f) 
{}

     void Voter::AddBallotPaper(BallotPaper b)
    {
          _bp.push_back(b);  
    }

    std::vector<BallotPaper>& Voter::getBallotPapers()
    {
         return this->_bp;
    }

//HOW DO YOU VOTE?
     void Voter::Vote(int paperindex,int index)
     {
           getBallotPapers()[paperindex].ChoiceVoted(index);   
     }
}
```

BallotPaper class

```
class BallotPaper
{
      private:
          PositionType _positionbp;
      std::vector<Candidate> _candidatesbp;   // only contain the required candidate
      public:
          BallotPaper::BallotPaper(PositionType a)
          {
             _positionbp = a;
          }

          std::vector<Candidate>& BallotPaper::getCandidates()
          {
              return this->_candidatesbp;
          }

         void BallotPaper::AddCandidate(Candidate c)
         {
             _candidatesbp.push_back(c);
         }

         void BallotPaper::ChoiceVoted(int index)
         {
             getCandidates()[index].IncreaseVoteCount();
         }
}
```

Candidate Class

```
 class Candidate :public Member
{
     private:
         int _votecount;
         PositionType _position;
     public:
         void Candidate::IncreaseVoteCount()
         {
             _votecount++;
         }
}
```

Comment: Your code is very hard to follow with most of it starting on the left margin of the edit window.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Hi, i have done some editing, hope that is much clearer to read!

Comment: `void Voter::AddBallotPaper(BallotPaper b)` -- Your compiler accepted this syntax (you do this with every line)?  An inline class member function need not have the class name proceed the member function name.  That is what is done if you were to move the implementation outside the class.  Expected: `void AddBallotPaper(BallotPaper b) { code }`

Comment: Also, where are the closing braces for these classes?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie actually each class has a header and cpp file, the`void Voter::AddBallotPaper(BallotPaper b)` is in the cpp file, which is outside the class. I skip putting in hboth files because the question will be too long.

Comment: You should post code as-is, not shortcuts that may turn out to be valid, but incorrect behavior when the code is compiled and run.  Or strive to post a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The candidate created in your program is copied into the vector in `Voter v`. You should check the count using `v1.getBallotPapers()`.

An easier solution architecture would be to keep all `Candidate` objects in a *vector*, and the other vectors store `Candidate *`, so they can refer to the single definition of `Candidate`.